# Centos / Amazon SES

Tags: email, sendmail, postfix-mta, vps, amazon-ses

So basically I want to use my amazon linux instance to push mail and forward any incoming mail. I don't plan on having any actual email boxes, just forwards to real emails.  What's the best way to do this while also avoiding postfix's mysql.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by:

- Using standard postfix
- Setting up forwarding boxes
- Having Amazon verify the email (which cleared via the forwarded account)
- Setting up SPF records

Hope this helps someone else!